# Link hover CSS transition is not reactive enough

Tags: bug, user-interface, hyperlinks

I noticed today that the Beta SE sites have a transition on the hover style of many links (top menu, question list titles, body links).

```
-webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease-in;
-moz-transition: color 0.4s ease-in;
transition: color 0.4s ease-in;
```

It is important for link hover styles to be strongly reactive so that the user knows when they've centered on a target.  In addition to the time [spent to move their cursor to the link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts's_law), the user now has to wait at least a half second to be sure they are over the link — and with such a subtle transition, may not notice the change at all (which adds a significant amount of cognitive friction, since they are always unsure about what is under the cursor and what is not):

[image]

*(Top is visited, middle is hovered, bottom is unvisited)*

Please remove the transition, and ideally, make a stronger hover style. The Meta question list is better:

[image]

Comment: I have noticed the ease-in is a bit too slow (and then very sudden at the end). I don't think the transition is the problem, just the long length. A .1 or .2 second transition can be very nice.

Comment: A zillion links on the interwebs not changing color at all: why would people wait for some color? In my browsers the cursor changes to a pointer before the transition starts; it's that pointer that makes me understand I can click a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have shortened the transition timer on the links(except for top nav). the change will be in the next prod build.